# Expo's eas build command (iOS) failing when Authenticating with Apple Developer Portal

Tags: build, expo, apple-developer

My team has developed an application and is publishing to the respective app stores.

The user that is trying to build the app is a member of the organization with an apple developer account.

On running "eas build" we receive the following error

```
eas build  
✔ Build for platforms › All
✔ Linked to project @{user}/{ProjectName}
✔ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials {ProjectName} (default)
✔ Compressed project files 1s (11.8 MB)
✔ Uploaded to EAS 21s
✔ Using remote iOS credentials (Expo server)

If you provide your Apple account credentials we will be able to generate all necessary build credentials and fully validate them.
This is optional, but without Apple account access you will need to provide all the values manually and we can only run minimal validation on them.
✔ Do you want to log in to your Apple account? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … {user}@gmail.com
› Restoring session /Users/{user}/.app-store/auth/{user}@gmail.com/cookie
› Session expired Local session
› Using password for {user}@gmail.com from your local Keychain
  Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/security#keychain
✔ Logged in New session
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
    Error: Cannot extract key "teams" from response data of type string: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For other's encountering the same problem, this was fixed by simply going to the apple developer website with the team admin and accepting the new terms and conditions.

Comment: does it mean I should enroll Apple Developer Program Enrollment and pay $99?

Comment: @Cindy To publish to apple's App Store or TestFlight you need an Apple Developer Account, yes

Comment: Sometimes is just that Apple is in maintenance mode

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading to the latest version of eas-cli (v3.13.3) using `npm install -g eas-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, what fixed the issue for me was to set the `image` field in my `eas.json` file to `latest` instead of the default one.

```
{
  ...
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.